# URL compliance with W3C and WCAG

Tags: w3c, url-encoding

My website uses URLs made up of letters, numbers, forward slashes and dashes.
e.g. `http://mysite.com/page/some-subpage-here/`

I have been told that that is not in compliance with W3C and WCAG 2.0 encoding guidelines. I think it is, but I could not find the page for this on the w3c.org website.

Is there something I am missing and that kind of URLs (that are used all over the world) are non-compliant?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show whoever told you [http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt](http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)